# Link para abrir imagen

Tags: html, imagen, enlace, href

Tengo un texto con hipervínculo y quiero que al dar click en el texto, se abra una imagen en otra ventana o sobrepuesta a la pantalla tipo *popup*.

Actualmente lo que hace es descargar la imagen, pero necesito que se muestre.

```
<p style="text-align: center; display: inline">
    <span style="font-family: Monaco, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 22px; color: black;">
        <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF;" href="https://linkimagen.png" target="_blank">Calendario</a>
    </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías crear una pagina en blanco y hacer un link hacia ella, pero yo te recomendaría usar una librería, si estas usando jquery, te recomiendo jquery modal https://jquerymodal.com/

Para ello agrega lo siguiente a tu head

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
```

Luego solo debes crear un div e ingresar tu información

```
<div id="imagen" class="modal">
  <img src="tu-imagen.jpg">
</div>
```

y luego hacer un enlace que abra dicho div basado en el id

```
<p><a href="#imagen" rel="modal:open">Ver imagen</a></p>
```

Veras algo asi, solo que con tu informacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posiblemente debas agregar css personalizado para dar el formato que quieres, la librería es muy fácil de usar y esta muy bien documentada

Comment: Muchas gracias Bro, me sirvió mucho .... Aunque no logré cambiar el ancho para aumentarlo, solo me cambiaba el alto. Sabes cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Busca el elemento a editar con el inspector de código, pero puedes tomar de referencia la clase .modal, especialmente al width y max-with, que son los que debes de editar, prueba usar !important en caso de que no tome tus estilos, si mi respuesta te ayudo favor de marcar como aceptada

Comment: Perfecto, con el max-width si me dejó, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Ya marqué como aceptada la respuesta.